# Microphone not showing up in Audacity

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, microphone, audacity

The mic is visible in "PulseAudio volume control". It is not muted and volume is at 100%. I can see it picks sounds. It is also visible in arecord:

```
$ arecord -l | tail -n 3
card 3: Microphone [Trust GXT 232 Microphone], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ arecord -L | tail -n 39
sysdefault:CARD=Microphone
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Trust GXT 232 Microphone, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

The mic is *not* available for selection in Audacity (I tried all options, launched Audacity *after* mic was connected). It works oob in Windows 10 in Audacity.

I am using Audacity 2.1.2, PulseAudio 8 (Kubuntu 16.04).

AlsaMixer:
[image: AlsaMixer]

amixer:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 58 [91%] [-6.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Front',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Front Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Front Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 2 [67%] [20.00dB]
  Front Right: 2 [67%] [20.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Surround',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-64.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-64.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Center',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [-64.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'LFE',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [-64.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Line',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Line Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 46
  Front Left: Capture 46 [100%] [30.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 46 [100%] [30.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',1
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 46
  Front Left: Capture 0 [0%] [-16.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 0 [0%] [-16.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Disabled'
Simple mixer control 'Channel Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '2ch' '4ch' '6ch'
  Item0: '2ch'
Simple mixer control 'Digital',0
  Capabilities: cvolume
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 120
  Front Left: Capture 60 [50%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Capture 60 [50%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',0
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Front Mic' 'Rear Mic' 'Line'
  Item0: 'Line'
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',1
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Front Mic' 'Rear Mic' 'Line'
  Item0: 'Line'
Simple mixer control 'Loopback Mixing',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Enabled'
Simple mixer control 'Rear Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Rear Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
```

Not sure if the USB mic is there. I tried few other parameters where it seems to show up at the end.

`$ amixer controls`:

```
numid=35,iface=CARD,name='Front Headphone Jack'
numid=31,iface=CARD,name='Front Mic Jack'
numid=33,iface=CARD,name='Line Jack'
numid=34,iface=CARD,name='Line Out Jack'
numid=32,iface=CARD,name='Rear Mic Jack'
numid=30,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'
numid=29,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch'
numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Volume'
numid=39,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
numid=26,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Boost Volume'
numid=14,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Playback Switch'
numid=13,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Playback Volume'
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Front Playback Switch'
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Front Playback Volume'
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Switch'
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Volume'
numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='Center Playback Switch'
numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='Center Playback Volume'
numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='LFE Playback Switch'
numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='LFE Playback Volume'
numid=28,iface=MIXER,name='Line Boost Volume'
numid=18,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Switch'
numid=17,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Volume'
numid=23,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'
numid=25,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch',index=1
numid=22,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'
numid=24,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume',index=1
numid=12,iface=MIXER,name='Loopback Mixing'
numid=19,iface=MIXER,name='Auto-Mute Mode'
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Channel Mode'
numid=40,iface=MIXER,name='Digital Capture Volume'
numid=20,iface=MIXER,name='Input Source'
numid=21,iface=MIXER,name='Input Source',index=1
numid=27,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Boost Volume'
numid=16,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Playback Switch'
numid=15,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Playback Volume'
numid=37,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map'
numid=36,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'
numid=38,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map',device=2
```

`$ amixer contents`:

```
numid=35,iface=CARD,name='Front Headphone Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=31,iface=CARD,name='Front Mic Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=33,iface=CARD,name='Line Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=34,iface=CARD,name='Line Out Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=32,iface=CARD,name='Rear Mic Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=30,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=29,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=64,step=0
  : values=58
  | dBscale-min=-64.00dB,step=1.00dB,mute=0
numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=64,step=0
  : values=64,64
  | dBscale-min=-64.00dB,step=1.00dB,mute=0
numid=39,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---RW-,values=2,min=0,max=255,step=0
  : values=255,255
  | dBscale-min=-51.00dB,step=0.20dB,mute=0
numid=26,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Boost Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=3,step=0
  : values=2,2
  | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=10.00dB,mute=0
numid=14,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=13,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Front Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Front Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=64,step=0
  : values=64,64
  | dBscale-min=-64.00dB,step=1.00dB,mute=0
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=64,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-64.00dB,step=1.00dB,mute=0
numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='Center Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='Center Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=64,step=0
  : values=0
  | dBscale-min=-64.00dB,step=1.00dB,mute=0
numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='LFE Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='LFE Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=64,step=0
  : values=0
  | dBscale-min=-64.00dB,step=1.00dB,mute=0
numid=28,iface=MIXER,name='Line Boost Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=3,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=10.00dB,mute=0
numid=18,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=17,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=23,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=25,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch',index=1
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=22,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=46,step=0
  : values=46,46
  | dBscale-min=-16.00dB,step=1.00dB,mute=0
numid=24,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume',index=1
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=46,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-16.00dB,step=1.00dB,mute=0
numid=12,iface=MIXER,name='Loopback Mixing'
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=2
  ; Item #0 'Disabled'
  ; Item #1 'Enabled'
  : values=1
numid=19,iface=MIXER,name='Auto-Mute Mode'
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=2
  ; Item #0 'Disabled'
  ; Item #1 'Enabled'
  : values=0
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Channel Mode'
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=3
  ; Item #0 '2ch'
  ; Item #1 '4ch'
  ; Item #2 '6ch'
  : values=0
numid=40,iface=MIXER,name='Digital Capture Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---RW-,values=2,min=0,max=120,step=0
  : values=60,60
  | dBscale-min=-30.00dB,step=0.50dB,mute=0
numid=20,iface=MIXER,name='Input Source'
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=3
  ; Item #0 'Front Mic'
  ; Item #1 'Rear Mic'
  ; Item #2 'Line'
  : values=2
numid=21,iface=MIXER,name='Input Source',index=1
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=3
  ; Item #0 'Front Mic'
  ; Item #1 'Rear Mic'
  ; Item #2 'Line'
  : values=2
numid=27,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Boost Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=3,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=10.00dB,mute=0
numid=16,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=15,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=37,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR

numid=36,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR

numid=38,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map',device=2
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
```

Comment: Could you tell me what the Audio Host setting is set too. It's dropdown is located far left just above the time code bar.

Comment: @MichaelProkopec "ALSA", I don't have any other option. A field to the right from this is a mic combo box and I tried every option, none was working (either no sound or sound from other [builtin] microphone).

Comment: Can you show the output of amixer?

Comment: @MichaelProkopec I have added a screenshot from alsamixer to the post. Edit: Oh, amixer, not alsamixer, added that as well.

Answer (score 0):

One of the following Input sources should be set to Front Mic:

```
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',0
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Front Mic' 'Rear Mic' 'Line'
  Item0: 'Line'
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',1
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Front Mic' 'Rear Mic' 'Line'
  Item0: 'Line'
```

Something like the following tailored to fit your needs: [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21740/321418)

e.g. `amixer cset name='Input Source',index=0 'Front Mic'`

That should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply start Audacity then Preference --> Device --> Recording
Select Device pulse:Internal mic 0 (this works for me , for you maybe another)
Done